# C++ char assignment

Tags: c++, char

The task is to add a numerical value to all characters in the English alphabet and then by entering a word in the program, it should calculate its value. Anybody knows how this can be done?

Comment: Can you give us an example input and output? For example, what should "hello" map to?

Comment: This sounds like a task for you - why are you asking us? Make a start, when you get stuck, come back!

Comment: input:
a 4
b 5...
abba 
output: 18

Comment: Sounds like homework - if so you should tag it as such.

Comment: The main challenge here, as I see it, is to design how the input will be defined.  There are two sets of input - the letter values and the actual words to be calculated.  I would suggest the letter values are given to the program in the form of a (config) file as they probably won't change as often as the words, and the words themselves should be given to the program via standard input, as they will likely change very often.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the specific mapping from characters to integers, you can simply assign to an int:

```
char c = 'A';
int i = c;
```

On many architectures, this will map A to 65, B to 66 and so on.

To map an entire word to an integer, simply loop over the entire word and add the integers up. Your course should already have covered how to write a loop that inspects each character of a string.

So here is just some pseudo-code to give you the general idea of what I'm talking about:

```
int sum = 0
for each c in word
    sum += c
```

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you can add ints to C++ chars, do you?

```
char a = 'A';
char b = a + 1;

int b_int = b;

cout << b << " " << b_int;

//should print
//  'b' 66
//or something like that
```

Chars in C are just (byte-sized) integers, under the hood